# How do I rotate a string to the right until every letter has been rotated?

Tags: python, rotation, substring, slice

I want to rotate a word to the right, so that every letter has passed.

What I tried to do is make a function. It looks like this (*yeah yeah ik lmao*):

```
word = "Abobus";

length = len(word);

n = 1;

def rotation():
    for i in range(length + 1):
        c = word[0 : length-n] + word[length-n:]
        print(c)

rotation();
```

I **needed** the output to be:

Abobus
sAbobu
usAbob
busAbo
obusAb
bobusA
Abobus

**Instead**, the output was:

Abobus
Abobus
Abobus
Abobus
Abobus
Abobus
Abobus

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are splitting at an index in `word`, but then just putting the two pieces back together.  Also, you are not use `i` to move the split index.

```
def rotation(word):
    length = len(word)
    for i in range(length):
        c = word[-i:] + word[:-i]
        print(c)

rotation('Abobus')
# prints:
Abobus
sAbobu
usAbob
busAbo
obusAb
bobusA
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this rotates the string to the left. What should the code be to rotate it the other way around?

Comment: ah, i didn't notice that.  you just need to make the `i` negative.  see the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Another option (which has potential to be more efficient when working with large inputs) is to use `collections.deque` which is optimized for such operations:

```
import collections

word = "Abobus"
word_as_deque = collections.deque("Abobus")

for _ in word:
    print("".join(word_as_deque))
    word_as_deque.appendleft(word_as_deque.pop())

## output:
Abobus
sAbobu
usAbob
busAbo
obusAb
bobusA
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the logic of the program you have written..
This will work

```
word = "Abobus"

def rotation():
    print(word)
    n = len(word) - 1
    for _ in range(len(word)):
        c = word[n:] + word[0: n]
        n -= 1
        print(c)

rotation()
```